# What is Mobile Safari's custom URL Scheme?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, url-scheme

iOS URL Schemes allow web sites to launch apps like so:

- `twitter://timeline` launches Twitter
- `googlechrome://google.com` launches Chrome
- `fb://root` launches Facebook
- `______________` launches Safari? (not `http://`, since Safari won't launch from `UIWebView`)

What custom url scheme triggers Safari to launch (even from within another app's `UIWebView`)?

To clarify, I'm not looking for `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: request.URL];`

Instead I'm looking for how a website can allow a user to launch Mobile Safari from within the `UIWebView` of another app (Google Chrome, Twitter, etc.).

Example HTML links that pop open other apps:

```
<a href="twitter://timeline">Open Twitter</a>
<a href="googlechrome://google.com">Open site in Chrome</a>
<a href="fb://root">Open Facebook</a>
```

I'm looking for something similar to these non-working examples:

```
<a href="safari://google.com">Open Safari [Doesn't work]</a>
<a href="webkit://google.com">Open Webkit [Doesn't work]</a>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXLjF/8/) of the same: http://jsfiddle.net/gXLjF/9/embedded/result/

Try opening [this URL](http://jsfiddle.net/gXLjF/9/embedded/result/) in iOS Google Chrome and opening Safari with the links.

Comment: The only way to launch Safari is to use `UIApplication openURL:` and pass an http or https URL.

Comment: That's using a `UIWebView` within the app. That is the opposite of launching mobile Safari.

Comment: All http URLs on iOS open in Mobile Safari by default when you use `openURL`

Comment: @Adam, except when launched from another app inside a `UIWebView`.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes, I understand. I'm looking for how to break out of a UIWebView within another app that I have no control of (let's say Google Chrome) and launch the url in Mobile Safari instead.

Comment: That can't be done and that's a good thing. Let the user choose the browser. Your website shouldn't force the browser being used. Can you explain why you want to force a user to Safari from whatever app they are using?

Comment: @rmaddy, yes, the UIWebView is limited and disables iOS features like "Add to Passbook". In principle I agree with you. But I'm trying to provide the user with a choice — continue to operate within the UIWebView with a limited experience, or allow them to break out of the "frame" and take advantage of the full experience. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/gXLjF/embedded/result/

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm having a similar issue with the Facebook inApp Browser which is breaking my PayPal checkout.... grrrrrrr

Comment: atm the best solution is to use `x-web-search://?` or `x-web-search://?your-keyword`

Answer (score 3):

There is no Safari URL scheme.  If you make one up and use it in your html you can check for it though.

Implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.  Return 'NO' for the requests that you want to shunt to mobile safari.  Call `UIApplication` `openURL` with the request's URL.

Something like this:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    // all clicked links!
    if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked )
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: request.URL];
        return NO;
    }

    // or, custom URL scheme!
    if ( [request.URL.scheme isEqualToString: @"my-open-in-safari"] )
    {
        // remap back to http.  untested!
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: [request.URL.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"my-open-in-safari" withString: @"http" ]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: So there's no way you can use this from the web then.  For example, if I wanted to allow users to break out of an in-app `UIWebView` into Mobile Safari.  Are you aware if `UIWebView`s support `x-callback-url`? I've been reading about hacks that use this toggle between different apps.

Comment: I'm not following your question.  This IS for breaking out of a UIWebView into Mobile Safari.  No; I'm not aware of x-callback-url.

Comment: Yes, the above *is* for breaking out of a UIWebView within an app that you control (i.e. you are the developer). But this does not work for websites to allow their users to break out of a framed experience (let's say in Twitter's app — an app they do not control the source code of).

Comment: @Ryan Did you ever find a workaround for this ?