# How to open a url in Safari instead of the default browser (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, swift

I have loaded an html file in a webkit view inside my app. The html file acts like a search engine and has the following code which gets triggered when the users hits the search action:

```
function search() {
    var input = document.getElementById("search_form_input_homepage").value;
    window.open("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + input);
}
```

However, I need the result url to open in Safari. As of now, window.open loads up the url in the default browser. How do I achieve this?

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378919/how-open-link-in-safari-mobile-app-from-webview/53028249#53028249) that talks about different url schemes in Safari. But I am very new to JavaScript. This is in fact the first time I am working with JS. So I could not understand how to implement this. Can anybody help me with this, please?

Comment: You have no control over this. Why would you want to enforce a specific browser?

Comment: Why Safari specifically?

Comment: @Mitya Because it's a part of a safari extension. Ideally, I would do it in native code. But that is not possible in this current scenario as it has dependencies with the html file So I would like to do it using JS.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because it's a part of a safari extension. Ideally, I would do it in native code. But that is not possible in this current scenario as it has dependencies with the html file So I would like to do it using JS.

Comment: Use a different protocol than `https`, which the browser will always open itself, and register safari as a protocol handler for that custom protocol with the operating system.

Comment: @Bergi how? I am very inexperienced in JS.

Comment: @onetrueshady Research "custom protocol handler" and/or study the extension API of Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this using Swift. I added the following webkit delegate method.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        NSWorkspace.shared.open([navigationAction.request.url!], withAppBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.safari", options: .default, additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifiers: nil)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't control which browser to open via JavaScript code, it's related to the operating system / user default selection.