# How can I redirect a website from webview to safari on iOS using URL

Tags: ios, webview, safari, url-scheme

Many existing questions are about implementing on Object-C or Swift.
But I want to know what to do on the server-side.

For example, I tried to redirect to chrome like below.

```
// nodejs-express server at 10.0.1.4:5000
router.get('/gotochrome', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('googlechrome://www.naver.com');
});
```

and following picture is a screen shot of mobile messenger app.

[iOS messenger app (kakao talk)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dbwc.png)
when I click the message, in-app webview is opened and chrome is opened with www.naver.com almost simultaneously.

Would it be possible for Safari?

Comment: sorry for not uploading image. I have not enough reputation..

Answer (score 0):

Safari has no scheme like chrome, and you could implement it in your app.

please see also this.
[What is Mobile Safari's custom URL Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642223/what-is-mobile-safaris-custom-url-scheme)

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
But we have no native or hybrid app. Our service is a web-app and it must be opened in Safari on iOS. Is there any method to implement some codes in our client web page?